# Determining if Something is a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following subsets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a subspace?

a) $U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\,|\, x_1=\dotsb=x_n\}$

b) $U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\,|\, x^2_1=x^2_2\}$

c) $U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\,|\, x_1=1\}$

d)  All of a, b, c are subspaces

e) None of a, b, c are subspaces

I know the properties of a subspace, but I am confused on how you apply that here. I don't understand the actual procedure to test each one. Thanks

Comment: The "actual procedure" is to look at the definition of "subspace" - it probably has three requirements - and see if they are satisfied by the set you are curious about. Start with (a). If you get stuck, show what you've done and ask for help. There's one answer so far that shows that (c) isn't because one of the conditions fails. I hope you figure out the rest yourself  before folks here tell you the answers.

Answer (score 1):

$b)$ isn't a subset because the vector $x_1=(1,-1,...,0)$ and $x_2=(1,1,...,0)$ belongs to $U$ but $x_1+x_2=(2,0,...,0)$ doesn't belong to $U$.

$c)$ isn't a subset because the vector $(0,0,...,0)$ can't belong to $U$.

Answer (score 1):

To show $U$ is a subspace, you need to show $(1)$ that $\vec0\in U$, $(2)$ if $x,y\in U$ then $x+y\in U$, $(3)$ if $x\in U$ and $a\in\Bbb R$, then $ax\in U$.

Let's look at (a). Clearly $\vec0=(0,\dots,0)\in U$. If $x,y\in U$ then we can write $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ where $x_1=\dots=x_n$ and $y_1=\dots=y_n$. Then, $x+y=(x_1+y_1,\dots,x_n+y_n)$, and you can see that we must have $x_1+y_1=\dots=x_n+y_n$, so $x+y\in U$. Similarly, you can show $ax\in U$ if $a\in\Bbb R$.

What about (b)? Looking at condition $(2)$, if $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ are in $U$, so $x_1^2=x_2^2$ and $y_1^2=y_2^2$, then is it always true that $(x_1+y_1)^2=(x_2+y_2)^2$? You should be able to find an easy example where this fails.

Now we look at (c). It shouldn't be difficult to see that condition $(1)$ fails here.

Comment: You should also check whether it is non empty. You can easily do this by checking that $\bar 0$ is in it.

Comment: @Math_QED good catch! So simple that it can be easy to forget

Comment: I think I was more confused with the notation. I know you have to see if it meets the three properties. But for example I don't understand how you can conclude that the 0 vector is included in a. I'm not sure if i'm missing something about the problem.

Comment: @JanoyCresva I'm not sure what notation you're confused about. When in (a) we write $x\in U$ such that $x_1=\cdots=x_n$, we are implicitly saying that $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. So for instance, the zero vector is $(0,\dots,0)$, which must be in $U$ since $0=\cdots=0$.